# When to submit a question as an Ubuntu bug?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, launchpad

I have a problem with my computer (a reproducible crash), and posted a [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/49231/5719) here on AskUbuntu. I hoped that this is a known situation with a known workaround, or that somebody can spot what I did wrong, or that there will be advice for troubleshooting.

But now my question has an unusually low view count, and no answers. There were two comments, which left me with the impression that their authors were just as puzzled as I am. So I am unsure if I didn't stumble upon a bug, and a new one at that (at least I couldn't find another case of this problem with google, but maybe I chose unfortunate search terms).

So, what are in general good indicators that the abnormal behaviour of a computer is a bug and not something else? When should I abandon my question here and go bother the devs on Launchpad?

Answer (score 5):

Freeze and "It doesn't boot" questions are just fundamentally hard.

There's a bunch of things that can cause a computer to freeze, which is why if you do a search for "freeze" or "crash" on this site you'll likely find that you're not alone.

I would say in that case you're better off filing a bug report, especially if the built in tools have a crash report or something that might help a developer diagnose the problem.

Comment: I'd really like to see something along these lines as a kind of shared "expert system".  A bit like a cross between a wiki and a choose-your-own-adventure.